# creating a method that randomly returns a fish from an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, arraylist

Hello I am having trouble creating a method called catchAFish() that randomly returns a fish from an arraylist (in which I have created another method that adds to it). If an index is empty, it is replaced with null. My attempt is provided below, Here is my pond class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Pond 
    {
     private int numFish;
     ArrayList<Fish> fishes = new ArrayList<Fish>();

     public int getFish() {
      return this.numFish;
     }

     public Pond(int numFish) {
      this.numFish = numFish;
     }

     public boolean isFull() {
      return numFish == fishes.size();
     }

     public String toString() {
      return("Pond with " + this.numFish + " Fish");
     }

     public void add(Fish fish) {

      if(fishes.size() < this.numFish) {
       fishes.add(fish);
      }
     }

     public void listFish() {

         // iterate for every fish in the fishes ArrayList
         for (Fish fish : fishes) {
             System.out.println(fish.toString());
         }
     }

    public void catchAFish()
    {
    int randomNumber = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * fishes.size() - 1);

    fishes.remove(randomNumber);

    for(int j = 0; j < fishes.size(); j++)
    {
    System.out.println(fishes.get(j));

    }
    }

    }
```

Everything works fine. When I add all the fish to the arraylist it works, when I just want to run the program once it works fine (a fish at random index is removed), but when I run it with the following tester code it doesn't. I keeping getting errors. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
public class PondTestProgram 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
         //Create a pond with 10 fish
        Pond pond = new Pond(15);
        pond.add(new Fish(4, "Sunfish"));
        pond.add(new Fish(25, "Pike"));
        pond.add(new Fish(20, "Bass"));
        pond.add(new Fish(30, "Perch"));
        pond.add(new Fish(4, "Sunfish"));
        pond.add(new Fish(15, "Pike"));
        pond.add(new Fish(9, "Pike"));
        pond.add(new Fish(12, "Bass"));
        pond.add(new Fish(5, "Sunfish"));
        pond.add(new Fish(12, "Sunfish"));
        pond.listFish();
        System.out.println("");



       // Now catch 7 random fish
        System.out.println("Catching 7 random fish as follows ...");
       for (int i=0; i<7; i++) 
        System.out.println(pond.catchAFish());
        System.out.println();

        // Now show what is left in the pond
        pond.listFish();

        // Now try to catch 5 random fish ... but only 3 actually left
        System.out.println("Catching 5 random fish as follows ...");
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
            System.out.println(pond.catchAFish());
        System.out.println();

        // Now show what is left in the pond
        pond.listFish();



    }
}
```

I keep getting errors at the pond.catchAfish() part on the for loop and I dont't know why

Comment: Grief there are a lot of fishy questions today.  Is there a course lecturer advising people to ask for homework help here?

Comment: yeap @PaulHicks she said you guys are great if you're stuck on a certain part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return fish from catchAFish so you can't print it.
Arrays in java are zero indexed - so your random code is also wrong.

```
public Fish catchAFish()
    {
    if (fishes.size() == 0) {
        throw new Exception("No fish to be found here..");
    }

    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * fishes.size());
    return fishes.remove(randomNumber);
    }
```

Comment: There is no `[]` operator on lists. `remove()` already returns the value being removed.

Comment: thanks for the response! @user3259789 but i keep getting an error at: Fish f = fishes[randomNumber]; it says: Error: array required, but java.util.ArrayList<Fish> found.

Comment: Fixed per comment of Guillaume Poussel... Mostly c++ guy here lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your `catchAFish` method returns `void`. You probably mean for it to return the fish that is removed from the pond.

Try changing the signature to `public Fish catchAFish()`. Then store the fish you remove from the list so you can return it:

```
Fish caught = fishes.remove(randomNumber);
…
return caught;
```